# Remove "connecting to..." messages from browser/firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

My website project uses html, PHP, javascript, css and mysql. My page is always fullscreen. (so no browser bars etc) Everything that is being displayed, is controled by my code. However...

My page reloads a php page in an iframe every 0.5 seconds. (and more might be added) When the page is loading, I get a "connecting with 192.168.XXX.XXX", or something scimilar, in the left bottom of my full screen. How do I disable these kinds of messages?

Most of my buttons are already javascript functions, since they have to do multiple things, but with a href=, I also get that same display in the bottom of my browser. This really screws up my full-screen layout.

Things I've tryed: google, and changing z-index of my images, in the hopes it would cover up this "connecting with" info box.

I would like to get a CSS/javascript solution for this problem. If I need to change browser settings with the "about:config" page in firefox, that is also fine.

*PS: English isn't my native language, and my browser is also in another language then english. Tryed to find a solution on google, but could not get any relevant info, not even the name of that bar.

Comment: Try ajax any not reloading the webpage. I don't think you can remove the message using script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it isn't possible to fix this problem using any code on my web page. It is browser related.

Finding some help at the mozillazine.org forums, got me to some good search queries.

If you want to remove the status bar (that's what it's called), you can use the plugin "Status-4-evar". It gets you the ability to turn back time, and get some lost functionality back into firefox. It also allows you to disable the status bar. However... When in full-screen, firefox (version 43.something) then puts back the unwanted status bar, even if the plugin/add-on should have blocked it.

Second solution should be to create a userChrome.css file, and put it in some directory in your firefox profile. Finding this directory using the mozilla KB was really frustrating, since it isn't correct/out of date.

Correct location for your userChrome.css file should be:
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles*random string*.default\chrome\

c:\users\XXXXX\ could be different on other windows versions. The chrome folder might not excist, so just create it.

Then create the userChrome.css file, if it does not excist already, and add the following tekst:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */

.statuspanel-label {background:#FF9!important;color:black!important;font-family:"DejaVu Sans Mono"}

statuspanel {display:none!important}
statuspanel {max-width:90%!important}

statuspanel[type="overLink"] .statuspanel-label
statuspanel[type="status"] .statuspanel-label[value^="Looking"]
statuspanel[type="status"] .statuspanel-label[value^="Connect"]
statuspanel[type="status"] .statuspanel-label[value^="Waiting"]
statuspanel[type="status"] .statuspanel-label[value^="Transfer"]
```

After having done that, restart your firefox, and all status bar messages will be removed, even in full-screen.